# What Internet Explorer settings might affect SQL queries functioning differently?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, internet-explorer

Vague title, but it's tricky to word well in one question.

I have a site which uses a local database to store reviews, and in another table we store ratings of those reviews, so every time someone clicks a thumbs up / thumbs down icon next to a review a new entry is added to that table, much like the "is this review helpful?" feature you see on many sites.

This is done using a js function which triggered when either thumb is clicked on, which then calls an aspx page and in the C# behind we check if the user has already voted on that review, and if so to update the database appropriately (e.g. removing their vote if they have already voted in that direction).

This works well in Chrome and IE on the laptop I am working on. I have tried the latest IE 10 standards as well as IE 8 standards as the latter is what most people will be seeing the site with, but it partly doesn't work on someone else's computer with the same browser version installed and same standards set. I had this user log in to the site on my machine to see if it was a user account issue, but it worked fine for them on my machine.

I have tried loading the site in InPrivate browsing windows to prevent any caching affecting the issue.

It works for them to submit a vote, either up or down, and they can change their vote from up to down, and the database is updated correctly. If they try to remove their vote however, it simply doesn't work.

It's not a user issue, as it works fine for both of us on my machine, and for neither of us on their machine, so I figure it some browser setting of some kind.

Summary:
- Works in Chrome
- Works fully in IE on one computer
- Doesn't work fully in same IE on another computer

Any pointers?

Comment: Check if the browser is not set to work in compatibility mode on the machine where it does not work.

Comment: I don't think your question is quite accurate- the SQL queries are working fine, but the outcome is different. Two suggestions: Delete all cookies and history from your browser- does the same problem arise for you? If not, then sorry, you just lost all your cookies and history for nothing :p Secondly run the site in a debugger- step through what happens if you use the "clear vote" and if your friend does. I am confident this will reveal the problem.

Comment: Another thought- check your web server logs to find whether your friend's computer is actually sending a request to the web server at all. If not, you would need to look at any javascript around their request.

Comment: @glenatron how do I check all requests? In the log viewer I can see all compilation errors with details of the exception and things like worker processes.
I already tried deleting all cookies and history on both machines, and unfortunately I can't use a debugger (work environment restriction ¬_¬)

Comment: That depends a bit on what you are using for hosting- for example in IIS you can look in the folder configured in the IIS Manager for logging and you will find a few folders, you just need to find the one with the latest file and see whether there is a request made from the failing machine to yours. If in doubt ( and not on a production machine ) just delete all the log files and let it create a new one. Even just seeing whether there is a 200 response will tell you a request got through...

Comment: Also, do you have that "Careers 2.0" link over there on the right? Because if you're being expected to cut code and you're not being allowed to use a debugger, you might want to take a look there.

Comment: @glenatron I'm using IIS, I found the log file, and indeed the log doesn't show the request when trying to remove the vote. The javascript is a function with just a `.load` without any conditions needing to be met. I included an alert which should only appear when the load request is made as follows: `$('.div').load('url',function(){alert("load performed");});` and this alert does appear every time even when the database isn't updated.

Comment: Also, when you click on the thumb up and down icons, the colours change depending on what you've voted, which is handled in the same file as where the database queries are, but that file isn't showing in the log when for example we change from down to up voting, but the icons do change colour. Baffled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caching issue. This explains why the database was updated the first time, but each time after it wouldn't work properly. Using the code below to prevent caching:

```
    // Stop Caching in IE
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(System.Web.HttpCacheability.NoCache);

    // Stop Caching in Firefox
    Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```